# Why disabled fields are not providing values on clicking submit in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

I have used Ajax.BeginForm / Html.BeginForm for a view which sends an object to the controller on clicking submit. There are some telerik controls which are disabled conditionally. On clicking submit, the object is unable to retrieve the already existing value in the control since it is disabled. Hence object is made with null values. Any help?

Im using jquery to disable these telerik controls on loading the page.

```
Change.setDropDownValues = function () {

    if (condition) {

                 $("#A").data('tDropDownList').enabled = false;                            $("#A").data('tDropDownList').disable();
                    }
        }
        else if (condition) {

            $('#Pop').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //text box
            $('#ShortDesc').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //textarea
            $('#LongDesc').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //text area
            $('#Cont').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //text box

            $('#iDate').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //datepicker division
            $('#C').data('tDropDownList').enabled = false; //drop down list
            $('#C').data('tDropDownList').disable();  
        }
};
```

Can anyone say how to remodify so that I can fetch the disabled field values?

Answer (score 14):

That's how `disabled` inputs work. They never send the value to the server. You could use `readonly` instead if you want to prevent the user from modifying the value and yet send the old value to the server when the form is submitted.

Comment: Im using jquery to disable these telerik controls on loading the page.

Comment: And what's the problem? Instead of disabling then make them readonly as I suggested yo: `$('#Pop').attr('readonly', 'readonly');`. Otherwise you cannot expect to get their values when the form is submitted. It's simply how HTML works.

Answer (score 3):

you can use something like this

```
$(":disabled", $('#yourform')).removeAttr("disabled");
```

before submit.